# CordovaDeploy.exe not found, attempting to build CordovaDeploy.exe

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I get exception when trying to the run app in wp8.

```
cordova run wp8
```

Comment: CordovaDeploy.exe not found, attempting to build CordovaDeploy.exe...
app_location\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\deploy.js(96, 5) WshShell.
Exec: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: how you generate the cordova project?

Comment: using Cordova CLI http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: I was using, "cordova create " to create new cordova app.

Comment: Try to open the _.sln_ file found under `platforms/wp8/`. Does it tell you that you can only build Windows Store applications with this version of Visual Studio?